# How to avoid content inside <pre></pre> being cut off while printing in html

Tags: html, css, web, web-deployment

I have a lot of content inside a `<pre>` tag that I am printing. I am using media queries for the print style. Everything is fine except that the last line on the first page is cut. Half of it remains on the first page and the other half is displayed on the next page. I don't know how to shift the overflow to the next page.

[image: This is the print image]

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I had to add the following to the style sheet.

```
pre
{
display:inline;
}
```